# Getting 'CategoryNewForm' is not defined no-undef while working with redux-form

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I am curretly leanring redux-react and developing a simple application. 
I wanted to use redux-form into my app. In my components i have following code

components/AddNewCategory.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class CategoryNew extends Component {
    render() {
        const { fields: { title, desc }, handleSubmit } = this.props;
        console.log(title);

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h3>Create A New Category</h3>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>title: </label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                </div>  
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Description: </label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                </div>  
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>         
        );
    }
}
export default reduxForm({
    form: CategoryNewForm,
    fields: ['title', 'desc']   
})(CategoryNew);
```

When I runs application I am getting following error:
./src/app/admin/components/add_new_category/AddNewCategory.jsx
  Line 28:  'CategoryNewForm' is not defined  no-undef
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Please suggest me how do I can solve this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'CategoryNewForm',
    fields: ['title', 'desc']   
})(CategoryNew);
```

form name should be string